# How to unckeck automatically the "No Data Value" predefined on raster background on QGIS 2.14?

Tags: raster, transparency-opacity

I'm trying to import a bunch of rasters, but there is a parameter predefined on the TIFFs, where says that No Data Value should be marked. But I need this unchecked.

I opened the metadata, and found this lines:

```
<NoDataValue Sync="TRUE">256
</NoDataValue>
```

And even if I change that to FALSE, or remove completely the tag, or simply delete the files, the Rasters still are showing automatically with "No Data Value" checked.

This is the result I expect when I import the rasters:
[image]

But instead, all the rasters are been loaded automatically like this:
[image]

And I need to uncheck manually the box of "No data value" of every single raster like this:
[image]

What can I do to import all these rasters with no parameters of No Data Value?

Comment: What do you mean by "there is a parameters predefined on their files"? In which files?

Comment: @user30184 - On the rasters files.TIFF
All of them are predefined to mark the No data value automatically.

Comment: Do you mean that you are reading that XML snipped from inside of the .tiff image file? Or do you perhaps have also something like .tif.xml metadata file in the directory?

Comment: That's it. I have all files (.TIFF, tiff.xml, aux.xml, tfw, .ovr ) in the same directory. And inside this XML, I found a parameter defined to mark the No Data Value. It's some parameter that was created with the TIFF. Got it?